# Is it possible to execute python code on a device in transparent way if python is not installed on it?

Tags: python

Is it possible to execute python code on a device in transparent way if python is not installed on it?

Comment: Python is an "interpreted" language. This means that the environment has to have the python runtime installed in order for your script to run.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python: Can I run a python script without actually installing python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5539736/python-can-i-run-a-python-script-without-actually-installing-python)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you are asking for, but if you are using a mac (e.g. OS10.9), there should be a built-in python 2.7. In the command line terminal, you can type in :

```
USER$ python
## Python 3.5.2 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:52:12) 
## [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 4.2 (clang-425.0.28)] on darwin
## Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

There are also third-party web-based software such as [Python Tutor](http://pythontutor.com/) that you can use. Internet access required.

Answer (score -1):

There are many web based apps that you can find by searching in Google, such as: [repl.it](https://repl.it/languages/python3) and [Google Console](https://console.developers.google.com/).